# Can't install SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, bitnami

I am trying to install SSL, but I cant restart apache

```
/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf# sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
Unmonitored apache
Syntax OK
/opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : apache not running
Syntax OK
/opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd could not be started
Monitored apache
```

and got this error in log file

```
 [Sun Oct 06 10:18:18.967677 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 16507:tid 140079867070208] AH02579: Init: Private key not found
    [Sun Oct 06 10:18:18.967727 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 16507:tid 140079867070208] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
    [Sun Oct 06 10:18:18.967742 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 16507:tid 140079867070208] SSL Library Error: error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error
    [Sun Oct 06 10:18:18.967753 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 16507:tid 140079867070208] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
    [Sun Oct 06 10:18:18.967765 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 16507:tid 140079867070208] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error (Type=RSA)
    [Sun Oct 06 10:18:18.967776 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 16507:tid 140079867070208] SSL Library Error: error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib
    [Sun Oct 06 10:18:18.967787 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 16507:tid 140079867070208] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
    [Sun Oct 06 10:18:18.967798 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 16507:tid 140079867070208] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error (Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO)
    [Sun Oct 06 10:18:18.967803 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 16507:tid 140079867070208] AH02312: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting.
    [Sun Oct 06 10:18:18.967807 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 16507:tid 140079867070208] AH02564: Failed to configure encrypted (?) private key mysite.com:443:0, check /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/4ea303957fff9adb.pem
    AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

Comment: "Private key not found": you did not provide Apache the correct path to your private key associated with the certificate you want to use.

Comment: How can I provide Apache the correct path? I already have the crt, pem and bundle.crt files in /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. As Patrick mentioned, it seems that you didn't copy the file properly or the file you added is not a valid one. Please ensure you copy the Certificate file and Certificate key file to the apache2/conf folder and configure Apache (apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf) with them (SSLCACertificateFile and SSLCertificateKeyFile parameters). You can find more information in [our documentation](https://docs.bitnami.com/general/apps/drupal/administration/enable-https-ssl-apache/).